# How to remove composition indicator from BasicTextField in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to remove that current composition indicator in `BasicTextField`.

[compose code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwrQs.png)  
[ui result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXgJ1.png)

I tried to use

```kotlin
...
textFieldValue.copy(composition = null)
...
```

mas causa um loop :/

[attempt that causes loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llmz3.png)

I found the code snippet in `CoreTextField` that adds this underscore, but I couldn't think of how to remove it

[handler composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CksGa.png) 
[add underline span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb8zw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with:

```kotlin
object HighlightDefaults {

    fun OffsetMapping.Companion.offsetMappingSingleComposition(
        lengthText: Int
    ) = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int) = lengthText
        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int) = offset
    }
}

...
visualTransformation = {
    TransformedText(
        it.copy(spanStyles = spanStyles),
        OffsetMapping.offsetMappingSingleComposition(it.length)
    )
}
...
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNGNa.png)